# Here are the problems, with a small jQuery script(add input)

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

how can empty value input new. in input new not putting value and it is empty and value putting in input previous, no in input new. how is it?

For results, please fill out the input and clicked on add: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YxC6p/)

```
$(function () {
        $('a.add_input').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $mediumCell = $(this).closest("div.mediumCell");             
            var $class =  '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
            var $column = $(this).closest($class);
            var input = $column.clone().wrap("<div />").parent().html();
            //var find = $(this).closest($class);    
            //var clone = find.find('.mediumCell:first').clone();
            //find.find('.mediumCell:has("input"):last').after(clone);

            alert(input)
            $column.before($(input));
            $($class+' .add_input').remove();
            $($mediumCell).append('<a href="" class="remove_input"></a>');
            $($mediumCell).append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>');
        });
        $('.remove_input').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $class =  '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
            $(this).parents($class).remove();
            $($class+' .adda:last').append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you make a template of the repeated part instead of getting it from the html directly

I updated your code with a template `div` and when you click add I get its html and append it to main html

check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YxC6p/1/)

you can use the same idea for the second text input